# to delete files older than 7 days using Unix

Tags: shell, unix, while-loop

Requirement:

i am having the path where the files will be present .

i need to get the path from it and delete the files older than 7 days with name as *.logo* or *,out0* ..

ISSUE:tried the below but its going to many paths that were not listed..

```
 #reading source path from rem_logs.txt

cat rem_logs.txt | while read FILE_PATH
 do
   echo " Path obtained from rem_logs.txt --> '$FILE_PATH'"


   echo "File has to be removed from '$FILE_PATH'"

   #moving to the specified path above
        find  $FILE_PATH -type f -mtime +7 -print | while read FILE_NAME

   echo "File is '$FILE_NAME'"
      do
          chmod 777 $FILE_NAME


         echo "$FILE_NAME is received"
              if [ "$FILE_NAME"=*.log0* -o "$FILE_NAME"=*.out0*] 
                 then 
                     echo " $FILE_PATH/$FILE_NAME" > $LOGPATH/abdul.txt
```

## used above statement for testing in testing environment

```
                 else 
                     echo "This file - $FILE_NAME need not be removed"
              fi
        done
        UpdateLog_del.sh "$FILE_NAME is presently deleted from the above mentioned path"   

done
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider doing something like this:

```
while read FILE_PATH
 do
    #for each filename found
    for FILE_NAME in $(find  $FILE_PATH \( -name "*.log0" -o -name "*.out0" \) -type f  -mtime +7 -print)
      do
         chmod 777 $FILE_NAME
         echo "$FILE_NAME" >> $LOGPATH/abdul.txt
      done
      UpdateLog_del.sh "$FILE_NAME is presently deleted from the above mentioned path"
#read from rem_logs.txt which contains the paths
done < rem_logs.txt
```

Comment: This will print not delete??!!

Comment: Thks but my problem is also that it is searching in many other paths than the paths listed in rem_logs.txt

Comment: tried and received the below while adding set -x to script...++ INSTANCE_NAME=primeuat
++ LOGPATH=/primeuat/app/ariba9
++ UpdateLog_del.sh 'Started Running deleting script'
pwd is
++ read FILE_PATH
 its not performing any step after receiving file path...Thks in advance and i really appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find /path -type f -mtime +7 -regex '$\|.*log0$\|.*out0$' -print | xargs -I '{}' -n1 rm -f {}
```